# I want to read a value from a text file and compare it with a number

Tags: windows-7, powershell, shell-script

I am using windows powershell. I want to retrieve a number which is stored in a text file and compare it with some other number using a shell script. If I use `$x=$(cat value.txt)` it says "command not found". 
When I use

```
cat vaue.txt
(
read num
)
if [ "$num" == '1' ]; then
echo "hello"
elif [ "$num" == '2' ] then
echo "world"
else
echo "hi" 
fi
```

the output contains "hi" irrespective of value of num. The else part gets exectued no matter what may be the value of num. Is there any other way? I have also tried all the other ways of reading a value from a file.

Comment: That looks like unix shell script. That won't work in PowerShell. PowerShell has its own syntax.

Comment: unix shell script can be run in powershell. i run shell script using command sh file2.sh.

Comment: @Kshitijbhat You can call a shell script from PowerShell, and the shell script will execute in a separate shell interpreter process. But the PowerShell runtime cannot execute shell commands. It sounds like your problem is with the shell script, not PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell has built-in aliases to for some functionally equivalent shell commands. As you have discovered the **cat** command works perfectly fine.

```
CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Alias           cat -> Get-Content
```

However, Powershell and shell scripts differ in syntax. The above should be written using the **if** statement shown below instead.

```
cat value.txt | % {

    if ($_ -eq '1') { "hello" }
    elseif ($_ -eq '2') { 'world' }
    else { 'hi' }
}
```